# C++ - Data read from memory has different type according to input

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, auto

I need to read data from the memory, when each time if can be different type and I know the required type when comparing two other variables.
After the condition there is a loop that is pretty much the same except for one assignment.

If I define the variable in the condition, I can't use it out of scope.
I'm trying to avoid duplicating the code.
(The code example is shorter than the one I use)

```
if (size == x) {
   auto data = reinterpret_cast<int *>(in->GetData());
} else {
   auto data = reinterpret_cast<float *>(in->GetData());
}   

for (int i = 0; i < batch; i++) {
   idx = rand()%total_size;
   int n = rand()%c;
   if (size == x) {
      labels[i] = n;
   } else {
      labels[i * c + n] = 1;
   }
}
```

Is there a C++ type or casting that can be used?

Thank you.

Comment: Not certain this will fit your use case, but you could put bulk of code in templated function. `template< class T> void func(T* data) {...};` and call it from inside the `if` with the correctly-typed `data`.

Comment: You don't show haw that `data` is used. Can you convert it to always `int` or always `float`? Otherwise - `union`, `variant`, polymorphism

Comment: @user4581301 how do you define the variable itself?  is it still auto?  if so, what is the initial value?

Comment: @VladFeinstein no, I can't convert it to one type. I'll try using union, thanks.

Comment: No need for variable at all: `if (size == x) { func(reinterpret_cast<int *>(in->GetData())); } else { func(reinterpret_cast<float *>(in->GetData())); }`